# How to keep full screen when show popup menu?

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar, navigationbar, popupmenu

I run my app on Tablet, which has both **status bar** (on top of screen) and **navigation bar** (on bottom of screen).
I use this code to make `Activity` **Full screen**.

```
 public void hideNavigationBar() {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(setSystemUiVisibility());

}

public static int setSystemUiVisibility() {
    return View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
}
```

Then when I touch a `Button`, I want to show a `PopupMenu`. The problem is: when `PopupMenu` is shown, the **status bar and navigation bar appear**.

I tried to add this line:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It works for the status bar. But the **navigation bar still appears** when show **PopupMenu**.

How can I keep full screen when show `PopupMenu`?

**EDIT**: Here is the code where I show the `PopupMenu`:

```
    ImageView btnOpen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_open);
    btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(ActivityViewImage.this, v);
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_image, popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    //do something
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394916/why-navigation-bar-is-appearing-in-fullscreen-apps-when-clicked-on-popup-menu

Comment: Try this: `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 0):

TOP you can try to this code hope this can help you..

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, sir. When I show PopupMenu, the navigation bar still appears

Answer (score 0):

Just call your `hideNavigationBar()` when the popup menu disappears. You can do this in your main activity like this (code in kotlin):

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    if (hasFocus) hideNavigationBar()
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not accomplish the exact behavior but making activity full screen immediately after context menu closed worked fine for my use case.

```
override fun onContextMenuClosed(menu: Menu) {
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu)
    fullScreen()
}
```

this is the fullscreen method i used:

```
fun Activity.fullScreen() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        val v = this.window.decorView
        v.systemUiVisibility = View.GONE
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        val decorView = window.decorView
        val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        //original code from stackOverFlow: View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
    }
}
```